# select tag is shown with a scroll bar

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am using select as a language switcher for my website but it is not shown correctly and whatever I do in the css file nothing seems to work. I want it to show as a regular select and I can't use drop-down button as it will redirect me to another html page which I don't want... Can any one please tell me what should I do

```js
 document.getElementById("selectLanguage").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("languageForm").submit();
    };
```

```css
.nice-select {
    overflow-y: visible;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
}

.nice-select:hover {
    border-color: #dbdbdb;
}

.nice-select:active, .nice-select.open, .nice-select:focus {
    border-color: #999;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.nice-select.disabled {
    border-color: #ededed;
    color: #999;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nice-select.disabled:after {
    border-color: #cccccc;
}

.nice-select.wide {
    width: 100%;
}

.nice-select.wide .list {
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}

.nice-select.right {
    float: right;
}

.nice-select.right .list {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}

.nice-select.small {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.nice-select.small:after {
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
}

.nice-select.small .option {
    line-height: 34px;
    min-height: 34px;
}

.nice-select .list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.11);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
    transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    z-index: 9;
}

.nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.nice-select .option {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    min-height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 29px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.nice-select .option:hover, .nice-select .option.focus, .nice-select .option.selected.focus {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.nice-select .option.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nice-select .option.disabled {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #999;
    cursor: default;
}

.no-csspointerevents .nice-select .list {
    display: none;
}

.no-csspointerevents .nice-select.open .list {
    display: block;
}


/* ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, */


.nice-select:after {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    content: "\e64b";
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    width: 5px;
    font-family: 'themify';
    color: #ddd;
}

.nice-select.open:after {
}

.nice-select.open .list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="languageForm">{% csrf_token %}
                                            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
                                            <select name="language" class="nice-select" id="selectLanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                                {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                                                {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                                                {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                                                {% for language in languages %}
                                                    <option value="{{ language.code }}"
                                                            {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                                                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                                                    </option>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Go">-->
                                        </form>
```

here is a screenshot of what it looks like

[image]

Comment: To get you started, remove the click listener (the first function you posted above) from your code - that way you can click the dropdown without navigating. In the end you *do* want the change listener (your `onchange` attribute in the html), but you might want to turn that off too while you sort out the styles.

Comment: I understand but I want to submit the form to send the option that I chose to the view so that it can translate the page